# How to implement unique usernames from a list of phrases

Tags: design, mysql

I am looking to create a random username based on a set of existing phrases plus an integer since there can be multiple users with the same phrase. For now lets assume there's 12 phrases such as `AnonymousPotato`, so a user who signs up could randomly receive `AnonymousPotato12345` as a unique username. The user would be stored in a MySQL table that has an auto incremented int primary key. I thought of using the id, but I don't think exposing the user's id is a good idea as it might expose information such as how many users exist.

The issue I am trying to work out is collision. How can I ensure the username generated is unique without having to expose an auto incremented database ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to ensure its unique, two ways immediately come to mind:

- pre-generate 1,000,000 unique user names (or whatever amount you think you might need).  When a user signs up, pull one from the list and mark it as used.
- After generating one, simply check if it is already in the database, and if it is, try again, and keep trying until you have a unique one.

I agree with you, you probably shouldn't use the user id as a public ID.  What I usually do is assign a public facing guid (in a column I call 'public_hash', usually a hash of the user name and some other info) to that user, which gets used in public facing urls.